# BlueJ Illegal start of expression error

Tags: java, bluej

I'm currently in an online computer science class at my high school. I'm working on a program which is supposed to take in the grades of several students from an outside document and calculate the final percent the students receives for the course and the letter grade that goes along with it by using a driver class and a main class. (Note that there are 4 grades for each student 2 quizzes one midterm and one final, the quizzes are graded out of ten and are worth 25% of the final grade combined. The midterm is worth another 25% and the final is worth 50%.) Every time I try to compile my code it gets hung up on an if loop that is used to determine the final letter grade, I don't know what is wrong with it, any help is greatly appreciated.

main code

```
public class StudentRecord
{
    private int quiz1;
    private int quiz2;
    private int midterm;
    private int test;
    private double finalpercent;
    private char finalgrade;
    public StudentRecord()
    {
        quiz1 = null;
        quiz2 = null;
        midterm = null;
        test = null;
    }
    public StudentRecord(int t, int m, int q1, int q2)
    {
        quiz1 = q1*10;
        quiz2 = q2*10;
        midterm = m;
        test = t;
    }
    public void setTest(int t)
    {
        test=t;
    }
    public void setMidterm(int m)
    {
        midterm=m;
    }
    public void setQuiz2(int q2)
    {
        quiz2=q2*10;
    }
    public void setQuiz1(int q1)
    {
        quiz1=q1*10;
    }
    public void setFinalPercent(int quiz1, int quiz2, int midterm, int test)
    {
        finalpercent = ((quiz1+quiz2)/2)*.25+midterm*.25+test*.5;
    }
    public void setFinalGrade(double finalpercent)
    {
        if (finalpercent => 90) THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR happens
        {
            finalgrade = A;
        }
        else if (finalpercent<=89&&finalpercent=>80)
        {
            finalgrade = B;
        }
        else if {finalpercent<=79&&finalpercent=>70}
        {
            finalgrade = C;
        }
        else if {finalpercent<=69&&finalpercent=>60}
        {
            finalgrade = D;
        }
        else 
        {
            finalgrade = F;
        }
    }
    public int getQuiz1()
    {
        return quiz1;
    }
    public int getQuiz2()
    {
        return quiz2;
    }
    public int getMidterm()
    {
        return midterm;
    } 
    public int getTest()
    {
        return test;
    }
    public double getFinalPercent()
    {
    return finalpercent;    
    }
    public char getFinalGrade()
    {
        return finalgrade;
    }
    public void inputinfo(Scanner.inFile)
    {
        private 
    }
}
```

Driver code

```
public class StudentRecordDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Scanner inFIle = null;
        try
        {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File("349f.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }       

System.out.pritnln("Studet\tQuiz1\tQuiz2\tMidTerm\tFinal\tFinal%\tGrade");
        int student = 1;
        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
            String[] grades = inFile.nextLine().split(" ");
            int quiz1 = Integer.valueOf(grade[0]);
            int quiz2 = Integer.valueOf(grade[1]);
            int midterm = Integer.valueOf(grade[2]);
            int test = Integer.valueOf(grade[3]);
            StudentRecord Student = new StudentRecord(int test, int midterm, int quiz1, int quiz2);



 System.out.println(student+"\t"+student.getQuiz1+"\t"+student.getQuiz2+"\t"+student.getMidterm+"\t"+student.getTest+"\t"+student.getFinalPercent+"\t"+student.getFinalGrade);;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well `public void inputinfo(Scanner.inFile)` doesn't look valid, for a start... nor the fact that is body is just `private`.

Comment: It's `>=`, not `=>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **lot** of syntax errors. for example, you can't null an int, only an Integer, `midterm = null` for example. Also the comparison `=>` isn't valid, it's `>=` which is probably where your error is coming from. You have '{}' around your IF conditions, which should be `()`... just to name a few.

I don't know anything about bluej but if it's missing basic things like that, you might want to switch to a better IDE like eclipse. that would definitely help clear up a lot of basic mistakes you might have.